# How to create Count IF Query?

Tags: sql, ms-access, count, ms-access-2007, iif

I have data in a table that looks like this:

```
VISIT ID | Surgeon | Surgeon Arrival Before Schedule in Minutes | ...
123      | Dr. A   | -45
156      | Dr. A   | -25
198      | Dr. A   | 32
...      | ...
```

I want to construct a query that will bin and count, meaning I would like an output like the following:

```
Surgeon | Bin 1 | Bin 2 | Bin 3 | ... | Bin 6
Dr. A   | 2     | 0     | 4     | ... | 0
```

Above, the Bin(s) are defined where the `Surgeon Arrival Before Schedule in Minutes` column falls into a bin with the following logic:

```
Bin 1 = Surgeon Arrival Before Schedule in Minutes        <= -30
Bin 2 = -30 < Surgeon Arrival Before Schedule in Minutes  <= -15
Bin 3 = -15 < Surgeon Arrival Before Schedule in Minutes  <= 0
Bin 4 = 0   < Surgeon Arrival Before Schedule in Minutes  <= 15
Bin 5 = 15  < Surgeon Arrival Before Schedule in Minutes  <= 30
Bin 6 = Surgeon Arrival Before Schedule in Minutes        > 30
```

I want to `COUNT` how many `Encounter ID` numbers fall into each bin to produce the desired result.

I have been trying queries such as:

```
TRANSFORM Count([or on time log].[ENCOUNTER ID]) AS CountOfID

SELECT [or on time log].[Surgeon]

FROM [or on time log]

GROUP BY [or on time log].[Surgeon]

PIVOT IIf([Surgeon Arrival Before Schedule in Minutes] <= -30, "Bin 1",
    IIf(-30 < [Surgeon Arrival Before Schedule in Minutes] <= -15, "Bin 2",
        IIf(-15 < [Surgeon Arrival Before Schedule in Minutes] <=0, "Bin 3",
            IIf(0 < [Surgeon Arrival Before Schedule in Minutes] <=15, "Bin 4",
                IIf(15 < [Surgeon Arrival Before Schedule in Minutes] <= 30, "Bin 5",
                    IIf(30 < [Surgeon Arrival Before Schedule in Minutes], "Bin 6")
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
;
```

Doing so gives me only bins 1 and 3 Surgeon which is not accurate.

Comment: This is essentially a PIVOT/CROSSTAB query: http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/make-summary-data-easier-to-read-by-using-a-crosstab-query-HA010229577.aspx you need to convert your bin logic into sql equivalents.

Comment: I have updated my question to reflect a rewrite of the sql based on the link you provided, thank you for it, it did help a lot.

Comment: I don't have sql2012 to test this on, but `a < b <= c` is a flat-out syntax error in 2008.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a first step, assign the bin number for each arrival.

This is the sample table I used.

```sql
VISIT_ID Surgeon Arrival
     123 Dr. A       -45
     156 Dr. A       -25
     198 Dr. A        32
```

The query below uses a Switch expression to assign the bin number, giving me this result set.

```sql
VISIT_ID Surgeon Arrival bin_number
     123 Dr. A       -45          1
     156 Dr. A       -25          2
     198 Dr. A        32          6

SELECT
    o.VISIT_ID,
    o.Surgeon,
    o.Arrival,
    Switch
        (
            o.Arrival <= -30, 1,
            o.Arrival <= -15, 2,
            o.Arrival <=   0, 3,
            o.Arrival <=  15, 4,
            o.Arrival <=  30, 5,
            o.Arrival >   30, 6,
        ) AS bin_number
FROM OR_on_time_log AS o;
```

You can build on that with a `PIVOT` to return the bin counts for each surgeon.

Answer (score 0):

I am going about this a bit of a different way as described [at this link here](http://www.blueclaw-db.com/accessquerysql/histogram.htm)

Where the code goes like this:

```
SELECT [or on time log].Surgeon
, sum(iif([or on time log].[surgeon arrival before schedule in minutes] < -30,1,0)) 
  as Bin1
, sum(iif([or on time log].[surgeon arrival before schedule in minutes] > -30 
    and [or on time log].[surgeon arrival before schedule in minutes] <= -15,1,0)) 
  as Bin2
, sum(iif([or on time log].[surgeon arrival before schedule in minutes] > -15 
    and [or on time log].[surgeon arrival before schedule in minutes] <= -0,1,0)) 
  as Bin3
, ...
FROM [or on time log]
group by [or on time log].surgeon
```